# Upload bytes to a an SFTP server from an AWS Lambda function in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I keep searching everywhere and I cannot find an answer so my last resort is posting here.

My requirements are that I need to SFTP a file from an S3 bucket using a Lambda written in C# (.NET Core 3.1). Don't ask why or suggest alternatives... I wasn't the one to set the requirements. So I have written the code that does it using the SSH.NET library which works when running the lambda code using the Mock Lambda Test Tool on my local machine. However, the same code deployed to AWS times out after 30 seconds. The Lambda is in a VPC but an EC2 within the same VPC and Security Group is able to access the SFTP server so I don't think it's a network related issue.

Here is the code I'm using to upload:

```
try
{

  using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(server, port, username, password))
  {
    sftpClient.Connect();
    if (sftpClient.IsConnected)
    {
        sftpClient.WriteAllText(path, contents);
        LambdaLogger.Log($"Uploaded file to {server}");
    }
    else
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log($"Could not connect to the {server} SFTP server.");
    }
    sftpClient.Disconnect();
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LambdaLogger.Log($"An error has occurred while uploading to the {server} SFTP server. Error: {e.Message}");
}
```

Edit: The error I'm seeing in the lambda logs is Connection timing out after 30 seconds. That's the exception message.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Connection timed out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the VPC. When removing the VPC configuration and just trying to upload some basic text instead of accessing the databases within the VPC it was able to connect and not timeout.

You CAN use SSH.NET to create an SFTP connection and upload files to a server from a Lambda function.